# php time handling NULL as 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I have a database with times stored as `TIME` as in `00:00:00` format. The database accepts `NULL`, but I also use functions that convert the time to a 12-hour format for viewing only.

The problem is: when the time input is empty, the functions that convert the format are changing the `NULL` to `00:00:00` which I would be fine with, but I cannot get it to not print `12:00 AM` when converting it back to 12-hour time.

I need to either:

- Have the input go into the database as `NULL` not `00:00:00`

OR

- Display nothing when converting `00:00:00` to 12-hour time.

These are the variations of the functions I have been using, again it is working if the value is a real time.

```
function time_12_to_24_sql ($value, $default) {
    $time = $_POST[$value];

    return ((!array_key_exists($value,$_POST)) || $_POST[$value] == NULL) ? $defaultValue : date("H:i:s", strtotime($time));
}

function time_12_to_24 ($input) {

if($input == NULL) {
    $retVal = $input;
}
if($input == 'NULL') {
    $retVal = $input;
}
if (!isset($input)) {
    $retVal = NULL;
}
if($input == '12:00 AM') {
    $retVal = NULL;
}
if($input == '') {
    $retVal = NULL;
}
else {
    $retVal = date("H:i:s", strtotime($input));
}
return $retVal;
}

function time_24_to_12 ($input) {
    if($input == NULL) {
        $retVal = $input;
    }
    if (strtotime($input) == '00:00:00') {
        $retVal = '';
    }
    if ($input == '') {
        $retVal = '';
    }
    if (!isset($input)) {
        $retVal = '';
    }
    else {
        if(strtotime($input) > 0){ 
            $retVal = date("g:i A", strtotime($input));
        }
    }
    return $retVal;
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning NULL, maybe the function should return an empty string.

Comment: I would look on your table schema. Are you sure that you have "default null" for your time field?

Answer (score 5):

You're kind of abusing `strtotime()` here. What you want to be doing is using PHP's date formatting functions:

```
function time_24_to_12 ($input) {
    // empty checks for null, empty string, zero, false, unset, etc.
    if (empty($input)) {
        return "";
    }
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", $input);
    $time = $date->format("h:i:s A");
    return ($time === "12:00:00 AM") ? "" : $time;
}

function time_12_to_24 ($input) {
    if (empty($input)) {
        return "";
    }
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("h:i:s A", $input);
    $time = $date->format("H:i:s");

    return ($time === "00:00:00") ? "" : $time;
}
```

(If you wanted to get fancy you could do a regular expression check on the input, instead of just checking for empty.)

Now this should work as you're looking for:

```
echo time_24_to_12("23:34:29") . "\n";
echo time_24_to_12("00:00:00") . "\n";
echo time_24_to_12("") . "\n";

echo time_12_to_24("11:34:29 PM") . "\n";
echo time_12_to_24("12:00:00 AM") . "\n";
echo time_12_to_24(null) . "\n";
```

Result:

```
11:34:29 PM


23:34:29
```

Comment: This helped. I had to change it to only create the date if `$input` was not empty, as I wanted to not print 12:00 AM or 00:00:00. But this got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: So this actually doesn't work for entries that have the time. Only for `null`

Comment: You can see my output at the bottom of the answer, it works fine. I assume the change you mentioned in your first comment was a simple check on the output before returning it?